# Instabilidade recuperando lista objetos atualizados

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring

Estou enfrentando problemas com Hibernate que parece estar relacionado ao objeto de cache.

Eu tenho uma entidade, vamos chamá-la A, com um atributo lista mapeada com `@OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "atributo")`. Os objetos da lista são entidades de classe B e tem um relacionamento bidirecional com A. Então B tem um atributo mapeado com `@ManyToOne (cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)`. Recebo o objeto A a partir do banco de dados e adiciono um novo objeto B na lista A usando a chamada e `Session.update(A)`.

O problema surge quando listo todos os objetos do tipo A, usando a chamada `session.createCriteria(A.class).list();`, acesso exatamente a um objeto A que atualizei e o objeto B **NÃO** está presente na lista. Ao abrir o PostgreSQL, ambos objetos estão atualizados e corretamente salvos, porém algumas vezes na consulta realizada no Criteria os dados não são os mesmos (algumas vezes estão corretas e outras não).

Tentei usar session.refresh (A) após a atualização A, mas o problema ainda persiste.

---

Sobre o comentário do Caffé, acredito que seja isso mesmo que está acontecendo, porém ainda não consegui encontrar uma solução para o problema. Abaixo segue a implementação dos métodos save e update do GenericDAO:

** Note que nossa classe GenericDAO é implamentada usando *ThreadLocal*.

```
private static final ThreadLocal threadSession = new ThreadLocal();
private static final ThreadLocal threadTransaction = new ThreadLocal();

public GenericDao(final Class<T> objectClass) {
    this.objectClass = objectClass;
}

public Class<T> getObjectClass() {
    return this.objectClass;
}

public T save(final T object) throws HibernateException {
    try {
        final Session s = this.getSessionHibernate();
        s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(object);
        s.getTransaction().commit();
        s.flush();

        return object;
    } catch (final HibernateException ex) {
        GenericDao.logger.error(ex);

        Session s = this.getSessionHibernate();
        s.getTransaction().rollback();
        s.clear();

        throw new HibernateException(ex);
    }
}

public void update(final T object) throws HibernateException {
    try {
        final Session s = this.getSessionHibernate();
        s.update(object);           

    } catch (final HibernateException ex) {
        GenericDao.logger.error(ex);

        Session s = this.getSessionHibernate();
        s.getTransaction().rollback();
        s.clear();

        throw new HibernateException(ex);
    }
}

/**
 * Get session opened of the Hibernate
 * 
 * @return {@link Session}
 */
public Session getSessionHibernate() {
    Session s = (Session) GenericDao.threadSession.get();
    // Open a new Session, if this thread has none yet

    if (s == null) {
        s = this.getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().openSession();
        GenericDao.threadSession.set(s);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Tentei melhorar um pouco a formatação para a facilitar a leitura, veja se consegue deixar mais claro para obter respostas melhores.

Comment: Considere que quando você requisita um objeto, nem sempre ele é trazido do banco naquele momento - ele pode ser trazido da memória, então você não verá seus objetos filhos que tenham sido adicionados em outra sessão. Considere também que quando você persiste uma entidade, ela não vai para o banco necessariamente naquele momento mas sim ao final da transação JPA (ela pode ir antes se você der esta ordem ao contexto, mas se a transação JPA não for encerrada, a transação do banco de dados ficará pendente e a entidade não será vista em outro contexto).Enfim, mostre-nos partes relevantes do código.

Comment: @FernandoChavesBenbassat Teria que ver também o código que consome este DAO, o código que obtém, altera e persiste os objetos. Provavelmente este código é muito grande e colar aqui não adiantaria, então você teria que reproduzir o problema num ambiente à parte (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Neste exercício talvez você já mate a charada. Agora, no título você diz "instabilidade" - se o problema só ocorre de vez em quando, deve estar relacionado ao design das threads (você está usando threads, certo?).

Comment: @FernandoChavesBenbassat Outra coisa: por que o método `save` inicia e commita a transação e o `update` não? A gerência da transação que é usada pelo `update` pode estar causando a problema.